# Migrating outlook user to entourage

Tags: windows, mac-osx, outlook, migration, mac

Can anyone give advice or pointers to resources for migrating a PC Outlook user's email, contacts, etc, to Entourage 2008 on a Mac?  Most of what I see is from circa 2005, and I wonder if there is more accurate or effective information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.oreillynet.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/9928

Comment: I had seen that page but was put off by the age of the messages.  However one person recommended convertmyemail.com... looks like that's not such a bad solution for $15.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.entourage.mvps.org/cross_platform/win_mac.html

Answer (score 0):

I know its not helpful, but I can tell you that they'll be pretty disappointed.  In my experience, Entourage is a pile.

Comment: Interesting... I've been an Outlook and Entourage user for years, and I would not have characterized it that way.  What is it that didn't work for you?

Comment: want to cut and paste a PPT doc into an email
looses my contacts and have to take a few hours to rebuild, since it does not seem to have the file-as field that is used in Exchange, all contacts appear as no name. So every contact has to have the file-as field reset.
Calendar disappears at times
can't display the email I sent from my iPhone and I have to open Outlook or Webmail to view it.
can't read archives that I have from Outlook.
want to suggest a new time for a meeting, - have to decline and sent it as a comment.
want to add an attendee to a meeting that someone else scheduled.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you... you open a PPT, then select all and copy... then you open entourage and paste it into an email and send... poof, all your contacts are gone?  I just tried that and didn't observe that behavior.

Comment: Yeah the formatting doesnt really work on comments, so that all ran together.  There was line break between "email" and "looses". Anyways, if you're happy with entourage thats great - I guess especially if you've used it for years you're probably pretty used to it.  The bugs i brought up are pretty well documented and acknowledged.